# How can I make a ASCII to string converter in python using: ''.join(chr(i) for i in templist)

Tags: python, ascii, converters, chr

I'm trying to make an ASCII to string converter (not sure if that is correct terminology) using chr() but when I type in something like 68 (capital D), nothing happens. I'm trying to accomplish it using this idea:

```
>>> L = [104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]
>>> ''.join(chr(i) for i in L)
'hello, world'
```

I want it to run as a program with user defined input so I came up with this:

```
templist = []
number = int(input("Please enter an ASCII number here: "))
templist.append(number)
''.join(chr(i) for i in templist)
```

As I said above however, when I enter a value, nothing happens.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have tried printing templist but it just gives me back the number I want to be converted to characters (68).

Comment: In first case you're using REPL. In second, you're running custom script. In REPL last evaled value is printed implicitly. In script you need to print it explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to put ''.join(chr(i) for i in templist) in a print statement so the code would look like this

```
templist = []
number = int(input("Please enter an ASCII number here: "))
templist.append(number)
print(''.join(chr(i) for i in templist))
```